# MikTeX crashes after update, but not always

Tags: errors, pdf, miktex, compiling

After a routinary update, Miktex fails to compile my thesis -with pdflatex- or any kind of LaTeX document.

The message is:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again <.../pdflatex.log>
```

And in the pdflatex.log file, the only information I have is:

```
2017-02-24 15:31:51,920+0100 FATAL pdflatex - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2017-02-24 15:31:51,920+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2017-02-24 15:31:51,920+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Debug.cpp
2017-02-24 15:31:51,920+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 83
```

And the most strange thing is that this error **doesn't happen always**. Sometimes it compiles (after several tries), and sometimes don't (and with the same error message).

Comment: Try to update another time and to rebuild the FNDB.

Comment: Sorry but without more info it is impossible to help you. You can check if you really have all updates and if there are new packages. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490. You can also try to get more info with a trace https://miktex.org/diagnosing

Comment: Actually, I've just uninstalled and reinstalled the whole MikTeX to its last version, but the problem remains the same. I'll try to trace MikTeX to give you a better diagnosis.

Comment: If your question is solved this way, consider closing/deleting it.

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question please post it as answer not as part of the question. And please do not add `(SOLVED)` to the title of the question but accept an answer. If the answer is only a comment about a mistake, you can use a comment and close or remove the question instead of answering it.